# How can I wake-up a PC using a command? (i.e. equivalent to moving a mouse, etc)

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, display, wake-up

It doesn't seem like this would be very difficult, but how can I wake-up a PC by doing the equivalent of moving a mouse or pressing keys on a keyboard?

My PC is running Windows 10 and I only have the monitors enter sleep mode after 15 minutes.  The rest of the PC is still awake and doesn't use hibernate, etc.

I'm trying to use EventGhost to receive a TCP/IP command that tells the PC to wake up the displays but it's proving quite difficult.

Comment: [Wake on Lan](http://www.mylanviewer.com/rcmconfwol.html)

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/

Comment: Do you want to prevent going to sleep, like mimicking 'activity' events or as others linked, you are looking for a Wake-on-LAN utility? I believe it's the former, see if wscript.SendKeys will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

> **How can I wake-up a PC using a command? (i.e. equivalent to moving a
>   mouse, etc)**
>
> My PC is running Windows 10 and I only have the monitors enter sleep
>   mode after 15 minutes. The rest of the PC is still awake and doesn't
>   use hibernate, etc

### 2-Part Solution Suggestion

---

**Solution Part One**

Create a batch script *(example in solution part two below)* that ***emulates keyboard key strokes***. Schedule it with Windows **Task Scheduler** and tell it to ***wake up the computer to run the task*** at designated time(s) just in case you also need to "wake the computer" otherwise at those times—more than just the sleeping monitor (see source below for detailed instructions).

*(Again, example batch script at bottom to use for scheduling along with logic native to Windows that **emulates keyboard strokes** ([SendKeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)) which will wake up the sleeping monitor.)*

**SOURCE:** [How to Make Your PC Wake From Sleep Automatically - Further Detail](http://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/)

[image]

---

**Solution Part Two**

Use the below batch script logic to natively emulate keyboard key strokes with a dynamically built and executed VBS script with batch though. This will be the batch script to execute logic-wise as an example.

**Example batch script sending space mulitple times like pressing the spacebar**

*(You can use any other keys you need to with [SendKeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) as well)*

```
@ECHO OFF
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs

:VBSDynamicBuild
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys " "                                >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys " "                                >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys " "                                >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys " "                                >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys " "                                >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys " "                                >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys " "                                >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys " "                                >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
GOTO EOF
```