# How can I schedule my display to wake up?

Tags: windows-10, power-management, windows-task-scheduler

I want to schedule my Win10's system display to automatically wake up at the same time every day.

The display automatically goes to sleep on idle (computer is still running - just display off).

I already have an event profile set up in `Task Scheduler` but need the right action to do this.

---

Need an integrated Windows-native solution that doesn't require third party tools. The marked duplicate does not have a solution like that.

---

Here is a proper duplicate: [How can I wake-up a PC using a command? (i.e. equivalent to moving a mouse, etc)](https://superuser.com/questions/1018975/how-can-i-wake-up-a-pc-using-a-command-i-e-equivalent-to-moving-a-mouse-etc)

With answer: https://superuser.com/a/1018996/160458

Comment: So you think people have been withholding all solutions using only native features until the same question is asked another time?

Comment: I don't think that no. I do however only want such an answer. If one never arrives so be it. This is a seed - it may bear - it may not. I think anyone would be foolish to discount the plausibility that no further answers arrive for the marked duplicate merely because it is already marked as answered (less reason to add new solutions).

Comment: OK, I'll fertilize your seed.  :-)