# Can AutoHotKey control display states?

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey

Would like to know if AutoHotKey can control:

1. Display On/Screen On
2. Display Off/Screen to black

Found this online which was suggested to be able to turn a screen on but it doesn't seem to work: `PostMessage, 0x0112, 0xF170, % -1,, A`.

How can I figure out which parameters to post?

Comment: `sendkey {control down}{control up}` ? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it just needs some benign keyboard/mouse input to turn the
>   screen on.

No, that is possible using a command, please take a look:
[How can I wake-up a PC using a command? (i.e. equivalent to moving a mouse, etc)](https://superuser.com/questions/1018975/how-can-i-wake-up-a-pc-using-a-command-i-e-equivalent-to-moving-a-mouse-etc)

When you move a mouse or push a key, you trigger a hardware interrupt that will be sent to the operating system. And exactly this message can you simulate by sending a keystroke like [SendKeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html).